# Scaffolding ApplicationUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm using the default template for ASP.NET MVC 5 with EF 6.  It generates the Identity model as

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to manage and edit the list of users, so I scaffolded the identity model and it added the following line in the ApplicationDbContext class.

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<QProj.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

I know this is wrong, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you create a new `ApplicationUser` class, or inherit from `IdentityUser`?

Comment: @BrendanGreen As you can see from the code above, ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser.

Comment: So how did you "scaffold" the ApplicationUser?  Since your context inherits from IdentityDbContext, you shouldn't need the dbset defined in your class.

Answer (score 3):

Here are my steps if you want to manage **AspNetUsers** table that was generated for you when you enable migrations with all the default settings in place.

- First create your controller using MVC 5 Controller with views, using
  EFL

[image]

- Add your controller with the following settings. `Use async controller actions` should not be selected/checked here since `Users` DbSet doesn't support async unless we will be using UserManager. That would be a different topic.

[image]

- Go to the generated controller and rename all instance of `ApplicationUsers` to `Users`

[image]

- Lastly you can now safely delete `ApplicationUsers` on `IdentityModel` (on my case, it was line 37)

[image]

We need to remove the line 37 as I shown on the last picture since it will fail to build when you run `enable-migrations`. Since `IdentityDbContext<T>` itself already contains `Users` property. So no need to add additional `DbSet` under `ApplicationDbContext` class or any class that you declare for that matter. This property by the way was automatically added when you Scaffold `ApplicationUser`.

Answer (score 1):

These are steps made me successfully scaffolding ApplicationUser:

1. Refactor ApplicationUser name to something else, like MyAppUser,
2. Add Controller with EntityFramework, using model MyappUser, this will successfully scaffolding MyAppUser,
3. The Scaffolding will create property `DbSet<MyAppUser> MyAppUsers` for ApplicationDbContext, delete it
4. In newly created controller, change all occurence of `db.MyAppUsers`to `db.Users`

Then you're good to go, hope this helps

Comment: Could you elaborate further why? In particular steps 3. and 4.